# Why is the column Name not displayed in listbox?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Now, when the previous issue got resolved, there is a new issue that has risen. When I run my code, it gives me the column name as(which is obviously not my column name):

> System.Data.DataRowView

The code that I am using is:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == "select" || textBox1.Text == "SELECT" || textBox1.Text == "SELECT")
    {
        string cmdstr = @"select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = '" +comboBox1.SelectedItem+ "'"; 
        string conStr = @"Data Source=INPDDBA027\NGEP;Initial Catalog=Dev_Server;Integrated Security=True";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdstr, conStr);
        sda.Fill(dt);
        listBox2.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

Please Help.

Comment: Is this WinForms? Or WebForms? Or WPF? Or Silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a display member, if you have a complex object as a DataSource.

```
listBox2.DisplayMember = "COLUMN_NAME"
```

If you don't specify a DisplayMember, the default is to call `.ToString()` on each object. The default for that is the type of the object, which is why you get `System.Data.DataRowView`

**Side Note:**

Instead of :

```
if (textBox1.Text == "select" || textBox1.Text == "SELECT" || textBox1.Text == "SELECT")
```

You can use :

```
if (textBox1.Text.Equals("select", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: but would it work for a single table or any table that I select from the combo box?

Comment: @AnkushSoni Running a database query on text changed is very, very bad idea. This fires every time you write a single character or delete one.

Comment: I am aware of that, but that is what is required in my program.

Comment: @AnkushSoni Then just set the display member to the name of the column you want to show in the text box.

Comment: Got it. Thank You very much. :)